Compensate magnetometer tilt with the IMU in ROS
For outdoor navigation,

I have a magnetometer driver node publishing sensor_msgs/msg/MagneticField messages in mag_link frame (fixed frame relative to base_link)
I have an IMU driver node publishing sensor_msgs/msg/Imu messages in imu_link frame (fixed frame relative to base_link)

The question is : is there any node in ROS2 to compensate tilt effect (when my robot is in a slope) or do I have to create a custom node to handle it ?
I'm on ROS2 Humble
